# Возможна ли постановка тире перед "ведь" вместо запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Возможна ли постановка тире вместо запятой в следующих предложениях?

> Они были очень похожи, и неудивительно – ведь они были кровными братьями.
>
> Он сможет простить меня – ведь я его отец.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Они были очень похожи, и неудивительно – **ведь** они были кровными братьями.*  *Он сможет простить меня – **ведь** я его отец.*

1. **Тире** является более подходящим знаком (второе предложение в составе сложного предложения обозначает **причину**, а также имеет **присоединительное** значение).
2. Союз-частица ***ведь*** используется в **значении** союза или является союзом (в школьной программе).
3. Можно второе предложение рассматривать как **присоединительную** конструкцию.
4. **Запятая** возможна, если пауза не подчеркивается.  В конечном итоге по примерам из Нацкоруса видно, что выбор знака во многом определяется **структурой предложения.**

**Дополнительный материал**

**ВЕДЬ** II. союз. 1. Присоединяет предложения, содержащие указание на причину, обоснование предыдущего высказывания. Полагаемся на тебя, ты в. один знаешь дорогу. Пора домой, в. уже поздно.

**[Справочник по пунктуации](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_263)**

**Нацкорпус**

Алексей Слаповский. Гибель гитариста (1994-1995)
Ему опять есть чем жить — ведь он же не может, как другие, жить просто так, пустым или полупустым.

Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 1 (1978)
Бежать к директору — ведь он ждет его звонка.

Александр Солженицын. В круге первом, т.1, гл. 1-25 (1968) // «Новый Мир», 1990
Ну, подумайте сами — ведь я безумно люблю женщин!!

Юрий Трифонов. Дом на набережной (1976)
— Не знаю подробностей, ведь я не читал.

Comment: Не понимаю, почему в словарях пишут, что "ведь" может быть союзом, но при этом мои примеры, как вы говорите, – БСП. Если это союз, то как они могут быть БСП?

Comment: В грамматике это союз-частица (разг.).  В толковых словарях указана семантика слова, а не точное грамматическое значение. В школьной практике говорят "в значении союза". Обратите внимание, что "ведь" может находиться и в середине предложения, что нехарактерно для союза, также возможны соч. союзы "а ведь, но ведь".  Поэтому основными причинными союзами являются  ТАК ...КАК, ПОТОМУ ЧТО  и др. Вот тогда ставится запятая. В данном предложении для выражения нужного значения (причины и присоединения) лучше подходит тире.